# Scripts load order

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS to declare dependencies I need in my project. I've configured RequireJS so that jQuery is loaded. However, for some reason, the browser gives errors that jQuery is not defined (Bootstrap.js needs jQuery).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="./js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Is it because requireJS loads the dependencies asynchronously, so it might actually happen AFTER bootstrap.js has been loaded?

Comment: Remove `bootstrap.js` import from your html and add its dependency in your `main.js`

Comment: As you mentioned requirejs loads dependencies asynchronously and it can happen that your bootstrap.js file is loaded before jquery is loaded. Try to define bootstrap.js as a dependency in requirejs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery')
}
```

Bootstrap only checks for jQuery globally. By the time the browser tries to load Bootstrap, jQuery may not be there yet because RequireJS loads modules asynchronously.

Now Bootstrap doesn't export itself as an AMD module. In order to ensure that RequireJS to be able to load Bootstrap as well as ensure it loads after jQuery, you use the [paths](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) and [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) config. `paths` maps the module name to the module file, while `shim` tells RequireJS its dependencies.

```
paths: {
  // We tell RequireJS that `bootstrap` module is this file
  bootstrap: 'path/to/bootstrap.js'
},
shim: {
  // We tell RequireJS that `bootstrap` will need `jquery` loaded first
  bootstrap: {
    deps: ['jquery'],
  },
}
```

Then in your `main.js`, load `bootstrap` as one of its dependencies.

Comment: `require.config({
    paths: {
        'bootstrapBlah' : '../modules/bootstrap',`...` what does it do? I thought it only specifies the path of the module, so that when I use bootstrapBlah as my dependency, it will know where to find it. Apparently, it also loads the script even if I don't declare bootstrapBlah as a dependency anywhere. This is in my main.js file.

Comment: @user5539357 Yep, forgot about paths. Adding it in.

Comment: I'm just asking what 'paths' does, because, as I said, I initially thought it only let's me specify the module location, but apparently it also loads it. shim, if I'm not mistaken, let's me declare dependencies of modules that are not AMD-compliant (like in this case).

Comment: @user5539357 No, `paths` isn't loading bootstrap. It saves that location, then continues on, and then when it finds `require(['...', 'bootstrap'],` it thinks "Okay, I need bootstrap. BUT, I was told that instead of looking in the root directory, I need to look *here* instead". So if you cut out `main.js`, if I'm correct it will not load bootstrap.

Comment: @Katana314 Yup. `paths` only tell RequireJS where to look. Some module has to depend on it for it to load.